# Code Brain "Teaser" -- but not really

Tags: pseudocode

I'm just curious to see what you guys think about this. I heard a bunch of answers passed around the office and I want to see if you guys can have possibly a better one.

Question:

You have two functions outlined below:

```
function one()
{
    A();
    B();
    C();
}

function two()
{
    A();
    D();
    C();
}
```

How would you re-write this (anything counts, you could create classes, variables, other methods, anything), to reduce code duplication?

Each of the methods called changes variables that the other functions need to use. Methods A() B() and C() are already defined.

Comment: Definitely use HTML5 because that solves everything. ;-)

Comment: Should we assume that there are already defined functions A(), B(), C(), and D()?  If so, please edit your post and mention that,.

Comment: Anything counts?  If breaking code is included in that I would definitely remove the calls to `A` and `C` from `two`, no more code duplication! :)

Comment: maybe we can build some enterprisey system using RMI and stored procedures; and also an intern who reads it from paper and types it in again...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not all languages will support this approach, and the syntax of passing a function may vary between those that do, but the concept would be:

```
function one()
{
    refactored(B);
}

function two()
{
    refactored(D);
}

function refactored(middleMan)
{
    A();
    middleMan();
    C();
}
```

Comment: This is interesting. Say it's in C# using .NET 4.0

Comment: This is definitely a good approach in some cases. And of course it's possible in C#, you can just pass a delegate as a parameter.

Comment: @slandau Look into Action. private void refactored(Action middleman)
        {
            A();
            middleman();
            C();
        }

Answer (score 6):

There is no code duplication here. It looks fine.

Comment: Not terrible duplication, but you still have two methods that are basically doing the same thing barring one call.

Answer (score 2):

> Each of the methods called changes variables that the other functions need to use.

I would start by refactoring the entire class to use proper OOP.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of ways to refactor that code; which I would use depends on the specific application, as it may mean that I need to reconsider things at a higher level, e.g. redefine classes, or at worst review the entire application design because the duplication means I missed some key relationship.

Answer (score 1):

If your functions one() and two() are really three-liners as in the example, I wouldn't rewrite anything. You would loose readability and make the code much harder to understand for the next guy.

If the calls to A() and C() are actually larger blocks of code...
- define a base class with abstract method X() and a concrete
function any()
{
  A();
  X();
  C();
}

- define a class One where X() is implemented by B()
- define a class Two where X() is implemented by D()

Answer (score 0):

Here's one option.

```
function (triggerA, triggerB, triggerC, triggerD)
{
     A(triggerA);
     B(triggerB);
     C(triggerC);
     D(triggerD);
}
```

This way you're only calling one function to do it all, and skips whatever you don't need/want to do.

Answer (score 0):

If you have closures, lambdas etc. available, you could write

```
function one()
{
    three(B)
}

function two()
{
    three(D);
}

function three(middle) 
{
    A();
    middle();
    C();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You *could* (but probably *shouldn't*) make a class where `A()` is the constructor and `C()` is the destructor, and have `one()` and `two()` be methods of the class calling `B()` and `D()` respectively.

I said you probably shouldn't because OOP should be used to write code that makes sense and not for obscure optimization reasons.

Answer (score -1):

In C++ this is usually accomplished with RAII if the context makes sense... this pattern is usually A() = some init function, C() = some de-init function. There's usually also a context associated that's being initialized or destroyed as well.

```
   class bar
    {
        bar() {
            A();
        }

        ~bar() {
            C();
        }
    };

    void one() 
    {
        bar barvar;
        B();
    }

    void two()
    {
        bar barvar;
        D();
    }
```

Comment: That is hard to follow, especially if someone not expert at OO has to inspect the code